# JDBC on Android

Tags: java, android, sql-server, jdbc, permission-denied

I'm new to Android, and Java altogether for that matter and I'm having a heck of a time trying to connect my Android app to SQL Server 2005.  I'm aware that the preferred way of dealing with data is via the consumption of a web service, but for my purposes I'm opting to connect via a direct SQL Connection. That said, I added the JDBC4 jar file to my project, and ensured that port 1433 was open on my sql server (I tested this using a windows desktop app as well as a windows mobile app I had handy), but for the life of me can't seem to get my android app to connect do to a permissions denied error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host
10.0.0.217, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Permission denied. Verify the connection   
properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and
accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the 
port are not blocked by a firewall.".
```

I'm using my sa username/password, which again I tested on a different platform, so I know conceptually at least, it should work.  The following is the connection code I have in Eclipse:

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"); 
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://10.0.0.217;databaseName=star","sa","MyPassword");
```

Based on what I've been reading, everyone's solution was to add 1433 to their SQL configuration, but mine already is, and I also ensured the IP address was enabled.  I'm at a loss but hoping that someone had a similar issue that turned up a solution.

Any help would be great.  Thank you.

Comment: Make sure the TCP/IP net-library is enabled on SQL Server. By default, it only listens on named pipes IIRC.

Comment: It is, I checked both native client and network configuration, but both are indeed enabled and have their default ports set to 1433.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Do you have that line in your android manifest file?

Comment: I don't, didn't see that I needed to anywhere in the documentation.  I'll give it a try.

Comment: That worked...sorta. Now it has left me the following error: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "Socket closed".'  Is there a way to disable SSL in the manifest or connection string (I didn't see anything online)?

Comment: On a related note, putting "encrypt=false" in my connection string didn't seem to do it.

Comment: I switched to using the JTDS driver and it now works with the manifest change you suggested...not sure why the JDBC driver is having issues with SSL, but I can't seem to find a solution online and don't have the time to put into it.